# How can I optimize a query which depends on both COUNT and GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a query which purpose is to generate statistics for how many musical work (track) has been downloaded from a site at different periods (by month, by quarter, by year etc). The query operates on the tables `entityusage`, `entityusage_file` and `track`.

To get the number of downloads for tracks belonging to an specific album I would do the following query :

```
select 
    date_format(eu.updated, '%Y-%m-%d') as p, count(eu.id) as c
from        entityusage as eu
inner join  entityusage_file as euf 
        ON  euf.entityusage_id = eu.id
inner join  track as t 
        ON t.id = euf.track_id
where
    t.album_id = '0054a47e-b594-407b-86df-3be078b4e7b7'
        and entitytype = 't'
        and action = 1
group by date_format(eu.updated, '%Y%m%d')
```

I need to set `entitytype = 't'` as the entityusage can hold downloads of other entities as well (if `entitytype = 'a'` then an entire album would have been downloaded, and `entityusage_file` would then hold all tracks which the album "translated" into at the point of download).

This query takes 40 - 50 seconds. I've been trying to optimize this query for a while, but I have the feeling that I'm approaching this the wrong way.

This is one out of 4 similar queries which must run to generate a report. The report should preferable be able to finish while a user waits for it. Right now, I'm looking at 3 - 4 minutes. That's a long time to wait.

Can this query be optimised further with indexes, or do I need to take another approach to get this job done?

```
CREATE TABLE `entityusage` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `entitytype` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `entityid` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `externaluser` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `action` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `e` (`entityid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `entityusage_file` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `entityusage_id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `track_id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `file_id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `quality` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `size` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `file_id` (`file_id`),
  KEY `entityusage_id` (`entityusage_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `track` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `album_id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `number` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '2000-01-01 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `album` (`album_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 CHECKSUM=1 DELAY_KEY_WRITE=1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

An `EXPLAIN` on the query gives me the following :

```
+------+-------------+-------+--------+----------------+----------------+---------+------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys  | key            | key_len | ref                          | rows    | Extra                                        |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+----------------+----------------+---------+------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | eu    | ALL    | NULL           | NULL           | NULL    | NULL                         | 7832817 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | euf   | ref    | entityusage_id | entityusage_id | 108     | func                         |       1 | Using index condition                        |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | t     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,album  | PRIMARY        | 108     | trackerdatabase.euf.track_id |       1 | Using where                                  |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+----------------+----------------+---------+------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Why `eu.updated` is not grouped directly but after `date_format`?

Comment: running the date_format on updated for every row in eu is going to slow it down.  May want to look at how you are storing the data and do that work on insert.

Comment: probably a typo. but  `date_format(eu.updated, '%Y-%m-%d') != date_format(eu.updated, '%Y%m%d')`

Comment: If eu.updated is part of an index then all benefits of it will be lost using group by date_format(eu.updated, '%Y%m%d')

Comment: I need to be able to group by different periods...say, monthly, quarterly, yearly.

Comment: can i have some sample date on http://sqlfiddle.com/ and see the desired result please

Comment: @sbrattla - in table track there is no field parentid  **`parentid` (`parentid`),**. have you stripped some fields ?

Comment: Why do you `count(eu.id)` when you are actually counting file/track records? I find this confusing and would prefer `count(*)`.

Comment: `entityusage_file` smells like a many:many mapping between `entityusage` and `track`; is it?

Comment: Notice "key_len = 108".  Your table is defaulting to utf8?  Change all uuids to be `CHARACTER SET ascii` -- this will save a significant amount of space.

Comment: How many rows in each table?  (Apparently 8M in `eu`.)

Comment: @Bernd Buffen removed key for parentid. Yes, I did remove irrelevant fields.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner is there a practical difference between counting eu.id and *?

Comment: @sbrattla - how many rows give you the result from your query ?

Comment: The result is the same. Counting `eu.id` is just obfuscating what you are actually doing. You are counting records related to an eu (which would simply be `count(*)`). But you tell the DBMS to look at the `eu.id` for every such other record and count the record only when the `eu.id` is not null, which is always the case. The optimizer will see through this and internally convert your `count(eu.id)` to `count(*)`, but why confuse the reader?

Comment: @RickJames entityusage represents usage of an entity. That could be download or playback of a track, or download of an album, folder or any other entity. If you download a track, then a 1:1 entry in entityusage and entityusage_file will be created. If you download an album, then a 1:many entry will be created as an album "translates" into multiple tracks.

Comment: @RickJames nice catch about ascii; i didn't know about that but it seems very reasonable to me. Will changing this have any side effects at all on a live database?

Comment: @RickJames entityusage holds 7316180 rows, entityusage_file holds 7534951 rows and track holds 975427 rows.

Comment: @sbrattla - Shrinking the disk footprint (by using ascii, etc) leads to more rows per block which leads to a more effective cache which leads to less I/O.  I/O is often 90% of the time taken by queries.  (Unless, of course, all the data and indexes are small enough to be cached in RAM.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the GROUP BY operation is on an expression involving a function, MySQL can't use an index to optimize that operation. It's going to require a "Using filesort" operation.

I believe the indexes that Gordon suggested are the best bets, given the current table definitions. But even with those indexes, the "tall post" is the `eu` table, chunking through and sorting all those rows.

To get more reasonable performance, you may need to introduce a "precomputed results" table.  It's going to be expensive to generate the counts for everything... but we can pay that price ahead of time...

```
CREATE TABLE usage_track_by_day
( updated_dt DATE NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY (track_id, updated_dt)
)
AS
SELECT eu.track_id
     , DATE(eu.updated) AS updated_dt
     , SUM(IF(eu.action = 1,1,0) AS cnt
  FROM entityusage eu
 WHERE eu.track_id IS NOT NULL
   AND eu.updated IS NOT NULL
 GROUP
    BY eu.track_id
     , DATE(eu.updated)
```

An index `ON entityusage (track_id,updated,action)` may benefit performance.

Then, we could write a query against the new "precomputed results" table, with a better shot at reasonable performance.

The "precomputed results" table would get stale, and would need to be periodically refreshed.

This isn't necessarily the best solution to the issue, but it's a technique we can use in datawarehouse/datamart applications. This lets us churn through lots of detail rows to get counts one time, and then save those counts for fast access.

Comment: I'm marking this as the correct answer as it made me realize that - while possible to optimize the original query - I will need a different take on this to get results back from the database within a decent timeframe. I went along the lines of your approach and brought down from 4 queries at about 50 seconds each to a single query at 2.5 seconds. I also applied some of the hints from other answers (better indexes, ASCII collation on IDs). Thanks for your alternative approach!

Answer (score 2):

This is your query:

```
select date_format(eu.updated, '%Y-%m-%d') as p, count(eu.id) as c
from entityusage eu join
     entityusage_file euf
     on euf.entityusage_id = eu.id join
     track t 
     on t.id = euf.track_id
where t.album_id = '0054a47e-b594-407b-86df-3be078b4e7b7' and
      eu.entitytype = 't' and
      eu.action = 1
group by date_format(eu.updated, '%Y%m%d');
```

I would suggest indexes on `track(album_id, id)`, `entityusage_file(track_id, entityusage_id)`, and `entityusage(id, entitytype, action)`.

Comment: Make any difference the order you put fields on the index? In the case of track both are KEY, but `id` is PK and I usually put that first.

Comment: The order does matter. If you make an index like `(col1, col2, col3)`, that index will only be used if your query uses the first column, or the first two columns, or all three, but not if you just use the last two. Make sense?

Comment: @CptMisery Yes, but in this case both are used the PK is used in the `ON` and the `Key` in the `WHERE` just wonder if make difference here.

Comment: I concur with the indexing recommendations for `t` and `euf`.  I expect the "tall post" (in terms of performance) is the number of rows to be examined in `eu`, and the "Using filesort" operation for the `GROUP BY`. MySQL can't use an index for the GROUP BY because of the function wrapper, it's not on a bare column.

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza: Column order can make a difference. Sometimes it is recommedable to have both indexes, so the DBMS has the choice which to use. Here for instance selection could start with entityusage then join entityusage_file then join track. For this, indexes should be entityusage(entitytype, action, id, updated) or entityusage(action, entitytype, id, updated), entityusage_file(entityusage_id, track_id), track(id, album_id)...

Comment: ... But selection could just as well be vice versa, i.e. start with track, join entityusage_file and then entityusage. Then indexes should be track(album_id, id), entityusage_file(track_id, entityusage_id), entityusage(id, entitytype, action, updated) or entityusage(id, action, entitytype, updated). You can create all these indexes, then look at the explain plan to see which get used and then drop the unused ones (or keep them for other queries).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner . . . It could.  I am guessing that `album_id` is the most selective condition.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - It is almost never advantageous to _start_ a secondary index with the PK.

Comment: @RickJames Can you elaborate why? Or show some reference?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: because such an index would be redundant. A query that makes effective use of a secondary index with the primary key column(s) as the leading columns could also make effective use of the primary key itself. The one case I can think of where such an index *might* be of benefit would be a *covering index* with entries that are significantly *shorter* than the table rows. More rows per block may reduce the number of blocks that need to be accessed. But it would be a rare case where such an advantage (if measurable) outweighs the additional cost (cpu,memory,disk) of the index.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: If you have a specific test case that demonstrates an advantage of a secondary index (on an InnoDB table) which has the primary key as the leading column(s), I'd be interested in reviewing that.

Comment: @spencer7593 Im talking about this case in particular. Want understand why `track(album_id, id)` and not `track(id, album_id)` I tought the PK should be first because is the `JOIN`  condition.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: An index on `(id,album)` is redundant. With InnoDB, the PRIMARY KEY (in this case, the `id` column) is already the cluster key. The table itself is organized as an index. With an equality predicate on `id`, that means we're looking for at most one row. And accessing that from a secondary index isn't going to be any faster than accessing the table, which is already organized as an index.

Comment: Juan, Spencer -- `(album_id, id)` lets you efficiently look up by just `album_id`; swapping the columns prevents that.  Also, the Optimizer tends to shun any secondary index that starts with exactly the same column(s) as the PK.  OTOH, the "covering" comment is valid, though I rarely see it happen.

Comment: @spencer7593 my understanding is if you use `(id,album_id)` index instead of just `(id)` you dont have to do a lookup to get the `album_id` so is faster.

Comment: @RickJames Sorry, but I disagree. Dont know if is an `InnoDB` thing, but in my postgres db I get different result in the `explain plain` if I have one index like `(id, album_id)` instead of just `(id)` because the first one has to perfom a look up to get the `album_id` value. My question is why the swap. What should look first? the `PK` in the `ON`  or the `FK` in the `WHERE`

Comment: The optimal order for the tables is to _start_ with table `t` because of `t.album_id = '0054a47e-b594-407b-86df-3be078b4e7b7'`.  _And_ have an index _starting_ with `album_id`.  `(id, album_id)` will _not_ be used.  The order of columns in an index is important.

Comment: @RickJames I use this guide MySQL index [**TIPS**](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) and if we use old notation for `JOIN` all those are `AND` comparation and `STEP 1` say order doesnt matter in that case. But I will do a real test in db to be sure.

Comment: @RickJames Lol, I just saw the autor ... is that you ?

Comment: That's me.  I got tired of spelling it out.  Along with about 20 other common things I encounter in the forums.  (See links at bottom.)

Comment: Thanks for index recommendations; I went for a slightly different approach than originally but applied your index recommendations. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `entityusage_file` is mostly a many:many mapping table, see [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) for tips on improving it.  Note that it calls for getting rid of the `id` and making a pair of 2-column indexes, one of which is the `PRIMARY KEY(track_id, entityusage_id)`.  Since your table has a few extra columns, that link does not cover everything.

The UUIDs could be shrunk from 108 bytes to 36, then then to 16 by going to `BINARY(16)` and using a compression function.  Many exist (including a builtin pair in version 8.0); [*here's*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid) mine.

To explain one thing...  The query execution should have started with `track` (on the assumption that `'0054a47e-b594-407b-86df-3be078b4e7b7'` is very selective).  The hangup was that there was no index to get from there to the next table.  Gordon's suggested indexes include such.

`date_format(eu.updated, '%Y-%m-%d')` and `date_format(eu.updated, '%Y%m%d')` can be simplified to `DATE(eu.updated)`.  (No significant performance change.)

(The other Answers and Comments cover a number of issues; I won't repeat them here.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your insight on ASCII. I went for a slightly different approach than the one I originally had, but I applied an ASCII collation on IDs. Thanks!

Comment: Good suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

can you try this. i cant really test it without some sample data from you.
In this case the query looks first in table track and joins then the other tables.

```
 SELECT 
    date_format(eu.updated, '%Y-%m-%d') AS p
    , count(eu.id) AS c
FROM track AS t
INNER JOIN entityusage_file AS euf ON t.id = euf.track_id
INNER JOIN entityusage AS eu ON euf.entityusage_id = eu.id
 WHERE
    t.album_id = '0054a47e-b594-407b-86df-3be078b4e7b7'
        AND entitytype = 't'
        AND ACTION = 1
GROUP BY date_format(eu.updated, '%Y%m%d');
```

Comment: No. With SQL you mainly tell the DBMS *what* to do, not *how* to do it. That you put `track` first, doesn't mean that the DBMS will start reading with this table.

Comment: This query executed in 44.761 seconds on a "bare metal" server with SSDs which runs the database as it's sole task.

Comment: @sbrattla - can you please post also the **EXPLAIN** of it

Comment: Thanks for your help; I went for a little different approach but I valued your input very much. Thanks!